# Enter config commands once on cluster of cisco ios?

Tags: switch

If I have two Cisco switches in HSRP mode (active/active) (we are using two Nexus 7K/5K or 6500 switches)  - I need to enter configuration commands twice, once on each device.  So every configuration change takes double the time.

Is there a tool or way to make commands on both devices at once, or enter on one switch and have it automatically copied over with each config change?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-122-mainline/46741-backup-config.html Should help you out.  While as far as I'm aware, there's no established way to automatically send a command to two IOS consoles simultaneously, you can configure one switch, and then copy that config over to the other, saving yourself a good chunk of time.